# Uploading a file to WCF 3.5 service

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-3.5, file-upload

I have a .NET 3.5 WCF service.  It looks like this:

```
namespace FileUploaderWcfRestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IUploaderService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UploadFile?fileName={fileName}")]
        void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class UploaderService : IUploaderService
    {
        public void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents)
        {
            // save to disk code
        }
    }
}
```

In the web.config, I have the endpoint setup as follows:

```
<endpoint address="" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="FileUploaderWcfRestService.IUploaderService">
```

On the client, I try to call it with a WebClient object, but invariably get error 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

```
var wc = new WebClient();
string url = "http://localhost:23619/UploaderService.svc/UploadFile?fileName=todo.sdf";

byte[] data = GetBytesFromFile("ToDo.sdf");  // gets the file into a byte array
byte[] resp = wc.UploadData(url, "POST", data);
```

I've tried different variations of the URL but nothing helped.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting the ContentType header on the WebClient to the content type of the file?

```
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
```